# No corda-webserver JAR found. Have you deployed the Corda project to Maven? Looked for "corda-webserver-4.4.jar"

Tags: corda

I am getting No corda-webserver JAR found. Have you deployed the Corda project to Maven? Looked for "corda-webserver-4.4.jar" error. This is when I upgraded the app from 3.3 to 4.4

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you are defining web port without having the webserver module installed.

To fix please ensure that you add the following into build.gradle file under Corda dependencies.

cordaRuntime "$corda_release_group:corda-webserver:$corda_release_version"

cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-webserver-impl:$corda_release_version"

Once you do this rebuilt your project.

You should also switch to another webserver like Spring as Corda Webserver is now deprecated.

Comment: but when i define these dependencies corda-webserver-4.4.jar doesnot get download because i guess it doesnot exist